# How to debug Visio add-in that will not load in Windows 10

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-2012, vsto, visio

I have an add-in for Visio 2007, which works well on Windows 7, but the same add-in does not load when run on Windows 10.  In Visio's Trust Center, the add-in shows up as "inactive" on Windows 10.  The add-in gets into the registry, but LoadBehavior changes from 3 to 2 as soon as Visio starts.  I understand this to mean there was a runtime error when Visio tried to load the add-in.

This add-in is written in C#, Visual Studio 2012.  VSTO 2010 is installed (required for automatic Trust Center acceptance).  Maybe if I could find out what the runtime error is, I could make progress.  How can I find more information about this runtime error?  Breakpoints are not hit, anywhere in the add-in code, including InternalStartup().  It seems to fail before running the add-in code.  I set up Fusion logging, but did not find messages related to Visio or the add-in, and I am not sure this is even a relevant tool for this problem.  I also have set system environment variables VSTO_LOGALERTS = 1 and VSTO_SUPPRESSDISPLAYALERTS = 0 but I do not see any alerts or logs.

Another developer is able to run this add-in on Windows 10 from Visual Studio 2012, but we cannot determine what the difference is on that machine versus mine.  Several other Windows 10 machines are unable to run this add-in, since it always is inactive (LoadBehavior = 2).  The goal is to deploy this add-in on Windows 10, just like it is already deployed on Windows 7.

Comment: Have you checked the output window in Visual Studio when you run the addin?

Comment: @MoonBoots89 yes, the output window in Visual Studio is blank when showing output from Debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found AddInSpy to be helpful, but it did not point directly to the problem.
https://github.com/NetOfficeFw/AddInSpy

It showed me an error message from my Add-in:
“Add-in DLL path is not found”
but this is not the actual problem.  (The path to the add-in is valid.)  There is a different problem that caused the add-in to not load, which caused this somewhat misleading message in AddInSpy.

AddInSpy also showed the VSTOR version in use = 2008.  Searching VSTOR, I found many versions work with .NET 3.5.  My Windows 10 machine did not have .NET 3.5 installed.  After installing .NET 3.5, the add-in worked!

To summarize: AddInSpy helped (indirectly) find that the add-in was not loading because .NET 3.5 was not installed on my Windows 10 machine.